# Convert into ternary operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

Help me to covert below code into ternary operator

```
if($(window).height() < $('body').height()) {
    $('.footer-region').addClass('regFooter');
}else{
    $('.footer-region').addClass('stickyFooter');
}
```

Comment: `if (foo) {blah()} else {blurt()}` -> `foo? blah() : blurt();` and its real name is the [*conditional operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12), which is an example of a ternary operator.

Comment: `(condition)?(if true statement):(if false statement)`

Comment: An if..else block runs faster than an equivalent conditional statement, so only use `? :` where it makes sense (it does here).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of giving you the answer, let's give you a hint:

```
if(a){
    b;
}else{
    c;
}
```

Equals:

```
a ? b : c;
```

You can place the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) *in* the `addClass`:

```
$('.footer-region').addClass(a ? b : c);
```

That should be plenty to figure out what to do ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much, above logic helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
var classPrefix = $(window).height() < $('body').height() ? "reg" : "sticky";
$('.footer-region').addClass(classPrefix + 'Footer');
```